# MenuItem within MenuItem not using all available space

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a menuitem that contains a datatemplate of a menuitem. Problem is the menuitem within that is not taking up all the available space on the right. Is there any way I can fix this?

```
<MenuItem Header="Test" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Test, Source={x:Reference TestControl}}"
                                                      Command="{Binding DataContext.Test_Click, Source={x:Reference TestControl}}">
                                                <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding TestName}"
                                                                  Command="{Binding DataContext.Test_Click, Source={x:Reference TestControl}}"
                                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding TestId}">
                                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                                <Ellipse Fill="{Binding TestId, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}"/>
                                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        </MenuItem>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                                            </MenuItem>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you are observing is the built-in column spacing of the [default MenuItem's ControlTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates).

**Highlighting the culprit below:**
[image]

These column definitions are used to show any keyboard shortcuts that you may have for the menu item, as well as some hardcoded column padding of 13 (why? I have no idea).

**So to answer your question**, if you want to take up the available space on the right, you will need to override the MenuItem's Template with a ControlTemplate of your own that does not include these last two column definitions.